# pandas - use aggregation function on column for last n values of a datetime column in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with sportsbetting data containing: match_id, team_id, goals_scored and a datetime column for the time the match started. I want to add a column to this dataframe that for each row shows the sum of the goals scored by each team for the previous n matches.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and what you'd like the output to look like? Your description is clear, but it's easier to build an answer when we have something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up some mock data, because i like football, but like Jacob H suggests it's best to always supply a sample data frame with the question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)

d = {'match_id': np.arange(10)
        ,'team_id': ['City','City','City','Utd','Utd','Utd','Albion','Albion','Albion','Albion']
        ,'goals_scored': np.random.randint(0,5,10)
        ,'time_played': [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#previous n matches
n=2

#some Saturday 3pm kickoffs.
rng = pd.date_range('2017-12-02 15:00:00','2017-12-25 15:00:00',freq='W')

# change the time_played integers to the datetimes
df['time_played'] = df['time_played'].map(lambda x: rng[x])

#be sure the sort order is correct
df = df.sort_values(['team_id','time_played'])

# a rolling sum() and then shift(1) to align value with row as per question
df['total_goals'] = df.groupby(['team_id'])['goals_scored'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(n).sum())
df['total_goals'] = df.groupby(['team_id'])['total_goals'].shift(1)
```

which produces:

```
   goals_scored  match_id team_id         time_played  total_goals->(in previous n)
6             2         6  Albion 2017-12-03 15:00:00          NaN
7             1         7  Albion 2017-12-10 15:00:00          NaN
8             3         8  Albion 2017-12-17 15:00:00          3.0
9             2         9  Albion 2017-12-24 15:00:00          4.0
0             0         0    City 2017-12-03 15:00:00          NaN
1             0         1    City 2017-12-10 15:00:00          NaN
2             3         2    City 2017-12-17 15:00:00          0.0
3             2         3     Utd 2017-12-03 15:00:00          NaN
4             3         4     Utd 2017-12-10 15:00:00          NaN
5             0         5     Utd 2017-12-17 15:00:00          5.0
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this with aggregation functions, but here's a solution where, for each entry, you're filtering your whole dataframe to isolate that team and date range, and then summing the goals.

```
df['goals_to_date'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.sum(df[(df['team_id'] == row['team_id'])\
    &(df['datetime'] < row['datetime'])]['goals_scored']), axis = 1)
```